# i am trying to execute percentage of marks using abstract class in salesforce and i got below error

Tags: salesforce, abstract-class, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

```
public class StudentA extends marks \\child class
{
    public double maths;
    public double chemistry;
    public double physics;
    double percentage;

    public StudentA(integer maths, integer chemistry, integer physics)
    {
        system.debug('maths marks are' + maths);
        system.debug('chemistry marks are' + chemistry);
        system.debug('physics marks are' + physics);
    }
    
    public double percentage()
    {

        percentage = (maths+chemistry+physics/3);
        
        system.debug('percentage is' + percentage);
        
        return percentage;
    }
      
    public override void getpercentage()
    { 
        system.debug('total percent' + percentage);
           
    }
   
    
}


object: 

StudentA v = new StudentA(99,98,99);
v.percentage();
v.getpercentage();
```

Note: I am trying to calculate total percentage of marks obtained, when i executed it give me error "attempt to de-reference null object".

In output only marks are printed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.i)
error screen shot is attached and output is also executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrOzH.png)mgur.com/tiJe2.png

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the parameter values to the class variables

Please modify your code as follows:

```
public class StudentA extends marks \\child class
    {
    public double maths;
    public double chemistry;
    public double physics;
    double percentage; // can remove this line

    public StudentA(integer maths, integer chemistry, integer physics)
    {
        this.maths = maths;
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
        this.physics = maths;
    }
    
    public double percentage()
    {

        percentage = (maths+chemistry+physics/3);
        
        system.debug('percentage is' + percentage);
        
        return percentage;
    }
      
    public override void getpercentage()
    { 
        system.debug('total percent' + percentage);
           
    }
  }

     StudentA v = new StudentA(99,98,99);
     v.percentage();
     v.getpercentage();
```

Comment: Also, as you are extending the `marks` class, Make sure the first letter should be capital and this class has a Definition Modifier as `virtual`.

Comment: You can remove the class variable `percentage` as the scope of this variable is limited to the `percentage` method only.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in your variables but not setting them.

In your constructor do

```
Maths = maths;
Chemistry = Chemistry;
Physics = Physics;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the instruction which you provided and still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you still having issues?  If so can you post your new code and the error?